# Syntax error defining triggers in mysql 5.0.77

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

```
CREATE TABLE `applications` (
`id` int(2) NOT NULL,
`applicationID` varchar(36) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`applicationType` enum('M','W') character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`applicationName` varchar(30) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`applicationPath` varchar(100) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`isDeleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`lastModified` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

-- 
   -- Dumping data for table `applications`
   --

```
 INSERT INTO `applications` (`id`, `applicationID`, `applicationType`, `applicationName`,     `applicationPath`, `isDeleted`, `lastModified`) VALUES (1, 'a49af37e-7f4c-1032-a010-   c067c39cc60b', 'W', 'workshopWorkerWeb',   'http://www.workshopworker.com/workshopWorkerLogin/workshopWorkerLogin.html', 0, '2014-08-27   15:11:46'),
(2, 'a49af5c2-7f4c-1032-a010-c067c39cc60b', 'W', 'agriMapper', '', 0, '2014-08-27 15:11:46'),
(3, 'a49af702-7f4c-1032-a010-c067c39cc60b', 'M', 'promacRegistration',  'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ncbaclusapromac.ncbaclusapromac', 0, '2014-08-27 15:11:46'),
(4, 'a49af838-7f4c-1032-a010-c067c39cc60b', 'M', 'eBAF', 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ncbaclusapromac.eBAF', 0, '2014-08-27 15:11:46'),
(5, 'a49af996-7f4c-1032-a010-c067c39cc60b', 'M', 'extensionWorker',  'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pt.com.extensionWorker', 0, '2014-08-27 15:11:46'),
(6, 'a49afad6-7f4c-1032-a010-c067c39cc60b', 'W', 'promacAdministration', '  'http://ncbaclusapromac.com/clientLogin.html', 0, '2014-08-27 15:11:46');

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `applicationsUUID` BEFORE INSERT ON `applications`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF NEW.applicationID = '' THEN
SET NEW.applicationID = UUID();
END IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Gives:- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$

I know it is problem with the DELIMITER syntax but I can't see where.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `applications` (
   `id` int(2) NOT NULL,
   -- `applicationID` varchar(36) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `applicationID` varchar(39) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `applicationType` enum('M','W') character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `applicationName` varchar(30) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `applicationPath` varchar(100) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `isDeleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
   `lastModified` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `applications` (`id`, `applicationID`, `applicationType`, `applicationName`,     `applicationPath`, `isDeleted`, `lastModified`)
VALUES
(1, 'a49af37e-7f4c-1032-a010-   c067c39cc60b', 'W', 'workshopWorkerWeb',   'http://www.workshopworker.com/workshopWorkerLogin/workshopWorkerLogin.html', 0, '2014-08-27   15:11:46'),
(2, 'a49af5c2-7f4c-1032-a010-c067c39cc60b', 'W', 'agriMapper', '', 0, '2014-08-27 15:11:46'),
(3, 'a49af702-7f4c-1032-a010-c067c39cc60b', 'M', 'promacRegistration',  'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ncbaclusapromac.ncbaclusapromac', 0, '2014-08-27 15:11:46'),
(4, 'a49af838-7f4c-1032-a010-c067c39cc60b', 'M', 'eBAF', 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ncbaclusapromac.eBAF', 0, '2014-08-27 15:11:46'),
(5, 'a49af996-7f4c-1032-a010-c067c39cc60b', 'M', 'extensionWorker',  'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pt.com.extensionWorker', 0, '2014-08-27 15:11:46'),
-- (6, 'a49afad6-7f4c-1032-a010-c067c39cc60b', 'W', 'promacAdministration', '  'http://ncbaclusapromac.com/clientLogin.html', 0, '2014-08-27 15:11:46');
(6, 'a49afad6-7f4c-1032-a010-c067c39cc60b', 'W', 'promacAdministration', 'http://ncbaclusapromac.com/clientLogin.html', 0, '2014-08-27 15:11:46');

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `applicationsUUID` BEFORE INSERT ON `applications`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF NEW.applicationID = '' THEN
      SET NEW.applicationID = UUID();
   END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I have found that DELIMITER is a mysql Client command not a SQL Command. So its use depends on the client you are using. I was using phpMyAdmin 2.8.2.4 which does not support the Syntax